# O que é preciso para criar um idioma ou língua falada?

Tags: significado, etimologia, gramática, sintaxe, significado-em-contexto

Suponha que faça um livro e queira tornar -lo mais: - Íntimo e vívido com seus personagens. Além da gramática: - O que é preciso?

Também suponha nesse caso, uma determinada razão: - "Vindas e Idas" ; isto é: - "Migração". Seria correto pensar: - Então, por trazer várias culturas diferentes, um idioma poderia seria criado como: o preencher desta falta de negociação?

Disto, deduzimos: Se existirem dificuldades assim, um idioma poderia resolver. Pois, na contraparte de seus habitantes, uma negociação seria feita ou seja um idioma. Isto é, máquinas tem que falar o mesmo idioma, caso não iriam funcionar.

Tais afirmativas são apenas pressupostos de como é imaginado através de contos e não fatos reais de como nossos idiomas poderiam ser feitos. Seja um problema mais comum, como: negociação de bens ou migração ou até mesmo como uma questão de falta de entendimento.

Comment: A tua pergunta não tem nada a ver com a língua portuguesa em si mesma, mas quer saber como construir uma nova linguagem artificial que vários traços desejados. Talvez seja melhor perguntar em [linguistics.se] ou [worldbuilding.se], mas terás que escrever em inglês lá.

Comment: Aqui no stack exchange temos uma proposta para criar um site para línguas artificiais (constructed languages). Se te interessa, podes acessar e apoiar a proposta.